# Ionic 2 android performance

Tags: android, ios, performance, ionic-framework, ionic2

I've been working with Ionic 2 since it's beta versions in July, and I was really excited when the final version came.

But I believe there is a great difference in performance between the android and the ios deployments.

As a test, I used the conference app, the demonstration application from ionic team.

There is a video I have linked below, where one can see the Conference app (as is today) deployed following the instructions (--prod -- release).

I think it cannot go unnoticed the fact that there is lag, a slight delay when using the bottom tabs (especially the speakers one ~0:17).

Has anyone else noticed difference regarding the performance between ios and Android?

Has anyone released an ionic 2 android version of his (or the Conference) app where such delays are not present?

Or is its something we should bear with?

[Video Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aIu2iZeIzoc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Globally, iOS performances are much better on Hybrid apps. Yet it tends to become smoother on Android, with lastest webviews. 
Regarding this specific case: it seems that the conference app uses `ionViewDidLoad` to get/initialize the list of speakers. You may try to use `ionViewDidEnter` instead. It should result in a faster page transition, but a delayed initialization of the layout. See more about [NavController lifecycle events](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/NavController/).